# How to get hostname from IP?

Tags: python, hostname, nat, dhcp, sdn

I'm using python to develop SDN
I also wrote a virtual network function just like DHCP,NAT,Firewall,QoS
But I want to get computer's hostname from IP like 192.168.2.XXX
I try to use arp but it only can find IP and MAC address in packets.

So how should I get hostname from specific IP?
Should I try this in DHCP or NAT?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Try `socket.gethostbyaddr()` from the module `socket`

Comment: But I use socket.gethostbyaddr() only can get router's hostname(gateway's hostname).